# Xpath combine predicates with common ancestor?

Tags: xpath

I want immediate tr of table optionally wrapped in tbody:

```
//table[complex-predictor]/tbody/tr | //table[complex-predictor]/tr
```

I want to combine the predicates as:

```
//table[complex-predictor](/tbody/tr | /tr)
```

But it not works. What is the correct way to do this?

Btw, i don't want tr deep in table
(/tbody/tr<strike>/td/table/tbody/tr)</strike>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
//table//*[self::th|self::tr]
```

The main XPath returns all descendant elements of `table`, then the *predicate* (the expression in `[]`) filters the descendants to be returned to only `th` and `tr` elements.

> "*Btw, i don't want tr deep in table
>   (/tbody/tr<strike>/td/table/tbody/tr)</strike>*"

In XPath 2.0 or above you can do :

```
//table[complex-predictor]/(tbody/tr|tr)
```

But in XPath 1.0, I don't see a clean way to get this done without repeating the 'complex-predictor'

Comment: the expression `//table(...)` is recognized as a node test or a function call

Comment: An alternative in XPath 2.0 is `//table//(th|tr)`

Comment: @softwarevamp direct answer to your question is there is there is no way to combine predicates with common ancestor using XPath 1.0. So, you will need to find a different approach. If you can use XPath 2.0 or above, then the 2nd XPath in this answer (or the comment by Michael above) will do